# Why is my code not working anymore once I turn it into an app?

Tags: python, tkinter, cmd

I have just followed a tutorial to turn a simple article summarizing file written with Python into an app.
The code works just fine, displays a window for the user to enter an url and a button to process it all.
I turned the code into an app and now the processing does not happen. The interface does pop up, it is possible to enter an url, but no way to get a summary.

This is my code: (from the tutorial video of [NeuralNine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4DQYprjPSs))

```
import tkinter as tk
import nltk
from newspaper import Article
nltk.download('punkt')


def summarize():
    url = urltext.get('1.0', "end").strip()

    article = Article(url)
    article.download()
    article.parse()
    article.nlp()

    # make it so the boxes can be modified
    title.config(state='normal')
    authors.config(state='normal')
    publicationdate.config(state='normal')
    summary.config(state='normal')
    
    title.delete('1.0', "end") # delete any content that may have previously been in the box
    title.insert('1.0', article.title)

    authors.delete('1.0', "end") 
    authors.insert('1.0', article.authors)

    publicationdate.delete('1.0', "end") 
    publicationdate.insert('1.0', article.publish_date)

    summary.delete('1.0', "end") 
    summary.insert('1.0', article.summary)

    # make the boxes non modifiable by the user
    title.config(state='disabled')
    authors.config(state='disabled')
    publicationdate.config(state='disabled')
    summary.config(state='disabled')


# user interface
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("News summarizer")
root.geometry('1200x600') # window size expressed in pixels

# create box for one element
tlabel = tk.Label(root, text="Title")
tlabel.pack()
title = tk.Text(root, height=1, width=140)
title.config(state='disabled', bg='#dddddd')
title.pack()

alabel = tk.Label(root, text="Authors")
alabel.pack()
authors = tk.Text(root, height=1, width=140)
authors.config(state='disabled', bg='#dddddd')
authors.pack()

pdlabel = tk.Label(root, text="Publication Date")
pdlabel.pack()
publicationdate = tk.Text(root, height=1, width=140)
publicationdate.config(state='disabled', bg='#dddddd')
publicationdate.pack()

slabel = tk.Label(root, text="Summary")
slabel.pack()
summary = tk.Text(root, height=20, width=140)
summary.config(state='disabled', bg='#dddddd')
summary.pack()

urllabel = tk.Label(root, text="URL")
urllabel.pack()
urltext = tk.Text(root, height=1, width=140)
urltext.config(bg='#dddddd')
urltext.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="Summarize", command=summarize)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

And this is what I did to turn the code into an app, following [Tech with Tim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UZX5kH72Yx4)'s tutorial

- Go to the file where your code is
- In the path bar type "cmd"
- In the cmd write "pip install pyinstaller" + run
- In the cmd write "pyinstaller --onefile -w FILENAME.py"

Get 2 files

- dist → where your executable file will be found
- build → can be deleted

Answer (score 1):

Your code gets stuck as soon as it tries to execute `article.parse()`. This is because `newspaper` is a broken library in Python 3.

It can't convert the website from HTML to plain text properly and can't continue with the code and give you any results. Hence you don't see it when you press the button. If you still want to use your program you'll need to install Python 2 and run it in that. If you want to know what is going on in detail, there is a giant issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/codelucas/newspaper/issues/485) where the problem is explained in detail.

I didn't figure out why it works in the editor. It could be because of the extensions used for programming in python.